# Stuck on how to detect User bots in a JSON and return users identified with a given condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

I did a mock interview and was asked this question. I started to solve it but now Im stuck. Any solution and explanation would be appreciated.

You have a file of data each object looks similar to:

```
{"timestamp": 1487722870, "user": "Una", "action": "navigate"}
```

where the timestamp is the unix time, in seconds.

Write a `function bot_detection(input_file_path)` to collect all bot accesses of users that perform at least 10 actions within any window of duration 4 minutes and at least 5 correspond to the same action (eg, navigate )

output a list of bot names that you found.

For example, if you've established that the user Tran is the only bot in the system, the function should produce `["Tran"]`

My current approach:

```
 // the data looks like this. first i read it into my file

    {"timestamp": 1487184625, "user": "Eric", "action": "navigate"} 
    {"timestamp": 1487184655, "user": "Bill", "action": "browse"} 
    {"timestamp": 1487184685, "user": "Eric", "action": "key press"}
    {"timestamp": 1487184715, "user": "John", "action": "idle"}
    {"timestamp": 1487184755, "user": "Tran", "action": "search"} 
    {"timestamp": 1487098049, "user": "Tran", "action": "click"} 
    {"timestamp": 1487098079, "user": "Eric", "action": "click"}
    {"timestamp": 1487098109, "user": "Tran", "action": "click"}
    {"timestamp": 1487098139, "user": "Bill", "action": "navigate"}
    {"timestamp": 1487098169, "user": "Tran", "action": "search"}
    {"timestamp": 1487184716, "user": "Tran", "action": "search"}
    {"timestamp": 1487298169, "user": "Tran", "action": "search"}
    {"timestamp": 1487271407, "user": "Bill", "action": "search"}
    {"timestamp": 1487271467, "user": "John", "action": "navigate"}
    {"timestamp": 1487271527, "user": "Dave", "action": "browse"}


let data = fs.readFileSync('user_file.txt'); 
      let startTime = data[0].timestamp
      let timelaps =  startTime + 8 min
      let users = {}

for(let i= 0, let startTimeIdx = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
// check if user exist in users
  // push into user action
  // check timelaps is > timestamp of [i]
     // update timelaps
     // remove startTimeIdx from user till you find one that exist in the timelaps window
  // check is user you just added to has > 20 actions
      // check if user has > 10 of the same actions
           // mark user as bot and ignore all other cases if this user shows up again
}
example of users : {
  { Eric: {action: {navigation: 0, keypress: 1} , bot: true},
  { Bill: action: {browse: 1}},
  { John: action: {idle: 1}},
  { Tran: action: {search: 1}, bot: true},
}
```

Comment: Create a scrolling window of 4 minutes, and then do the two checks.

Comment: a scrolling window ? why @Keith

Comment: This question is really too broad to be answered here.

Comment: I changed the question....the main thing is to get a function that ratify two condition: users that perform at least 10 actions within any window of duration 4 minutes and  at least 5 correspond to the same action (eg, navigate
). @Herohtar

Comment: @Sayran  I was meaning in a metaphor sense.  Scrolling window of data, if you make it so that you make a subset of your data that covers the 4 minutes, and then move the data along, keeping within the 4 minute `window`, at each iteration check the conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is harder than it looks at first glance, however theres many ways of doing this.
As it is in the provided data there are no bots.
For something like this I would expect the data to be sorted by timestamp, which it is not, so I ended up having to sort the data first. 
code is below see comments in code for explanation

```
const fs = require('fs');
//get the data and split by \n 
//easier to run .each on it later
var data = fs.readFileSync('user_file.txt','utf8').split("\n");

//sort the data by timestamp
data.sort(function(a,b){
    var a=JSON.parse(a);
    var b=JSON.parse(b);
    return(a.timestamp-b.timestamp);});
//make users an array you can use object but array is just easier for me
var users=[];
//duration in seconds
const duration = 240;
//minimum number of actions that will consider user a bot
const minEntries = 10;
//minimum number of same actions that will consider user a bot
const minActions = 5;
//check and return the duration of the entries
function checkduration(user)
{
    var entries=user.entries.length;
    return(user.entries[entries-1].timestamp-user.entries[0].timestamp);
}
//array of bots
var bots=[];
//go through each line
data.forEach(function(log){
    //parse the log to json
    var jsonLog = JSON.parse(log);
    //check if user exixts
    if(typeof(users[jsonLog.user])=='undefined')
    {
        //create new user entry it is an object
        //which will contain all logs for this user and the check whther its bot or not
        //assume its not a bot
        users[jsonLog.user]={entries:[jsonLog],bot:false};
        return;
    }
    else if(users[jsonLog.user].bot==true)
    {
        //user is a bot, no need to check anymore
        //return to go through next user
        return;
    }
    //add on new entry
    users[jsonLog.user].entries.push(jsonLog);

    //discard entries longer than 4 mins ago
    while(users[jsonLog.user].entries.length>1 && checkduration(users[jsonLog.user])>duration)
    {
        users[jsonLog.user].entries.shift();
    }

    //see if have enough entries to check for bot
    if(users[jsonLog.user].entries.length==minEntries)
    {
        //has enough entries check for type of actions
        var actions=[];
        var maxActions=0;
        //get number of actions of each type
        users[jsonLog.user].entries.forEach(function(entry){
            if(typeof(actions[entry.action])=='undefined')
            {
                actions[entry.action]=1;
            }
            else{
                actions[entry.action]++;
                if(maxActions<actions[entry.action])
                {
                    maxActions=actions[entry.action];
                }
            }
        });
        //if actions is more than min required set as bot
        if(maxActions>=minActions)
        {
            users[jsonLog.user].bot=true;
            //add to list of bots
            bots.push(jsonLog.user);
        }
    }
});
console.log(bots);
```

Comment: Yeah it tricked me up at first as well.Your solution is a pretty straightforward solution. Appreciate it!!!!